# Anyone familiar with data format of Comfirmit?

Tags: python, spss

I recently asked about accessing data from SPSS and got some absolutely wonderful help here. I now have an almost identical need to read data from a Confirmit data file. Not finding a ton of confirmit data file format on the web. It appears that Confirmit can export to SPSS *.sav files. This might be one avenue for me. Here's the exact needs:

I need to be able to extract two different but related types of info from a market research study done using ConfirmIt:

1. I need to be able to discover the data "schema", as in what questions are being asked (the text of the questions) and what the type of the answer is (multiple choice, yes/no, text) and what text labels are associated with each answer.
2. I need to be able to read respondents answers and populate my data model. So for each of the questions discovered as part of step 1 above, I need to build a table of respondent answers.

With SPSS this was easy thanks to a data access module available freely available by IBM and a nice Python wrapper by Albert-Jan Roskam. Googling I'm not finding much info. Any insight into this is helpful. Something like a Python or Java class to read the confirmit data would be perfect!

Assuming my best option ends up being to export to SPSS *.sav file, does anyone know if it will meet both of my use cases above (contain the questions, answers schema and also contain each participant's results)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get the data schema from Excel definition export from Confirmit
2. You can export from Confirmit txt file with the same template

Comment: if you mean that when we export to Excel (or CSV) the top row is a legend with column names that is helpful. Or is there another way to an actual data dictionary?

Comment: yes. there are 2 ways to export excel files: the first one is the excel you're talking about. there is another excel file called excel defition. there you will recieve an excel with a list of column names and a starting column and an end column for each column name

Answer (score 0):

I was recently given a data set from confirmit. There are almost 4000 columns in the excel file. I want to enter it into a mysql db. There is not way they are just doing that output from one table. Do you know how the table schema works for confirmit?